# Python 3 cannot read my .txt file. How do I solve it?

Tags: python, string, utf-8, character-encoding

python 3 cannot read my file. The file is a Bengali word database. I wrote the following code:

```
x = open('c:\\BengaliWordList_112.txt').read()
```

The code is showing me the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-0b3d4d6e7768> in <module>
----> 1 x = open('c:\\BengaliWordList_112.txt').read()

~\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input, final)
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     22     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 23         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
     24 
     25 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 28: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: yes, it helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```py
x = open('c:\\BengaliWordList_112.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
```

Comment: This works. Thanks.